# php curl, detect response is gzip or not

Tags: php, curl, gzip

I'm using curl to fetch data from many website. Sometimes they send back gzip. How to detect response is gzip or not?

Comment: You need content-type header from the response. It should be helpful for you. http://www.satya-weblog.com/2010/07/php-curl-get-returned-content-mime-type.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
```

The result of `curl_exec` will then also include the headers from the HTTP response, which you can parse to see if it is gzipped.

A gzipped response would be like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 26395

[GZIP COMPRESSED DATA]
```

So, you can first break up the response into headers and contents and then parse the headers to see if it says anything about gzip encoded content.

Answer (score 6):

BTW, if you set:

```
CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
```

CURL will automatically decode the data for you.