# curl_exec returns unreadable text - cURL PHP

Tags: php, curl

I am trying cURL, but `curl_exec()` returns unreadable text like the screenshot below.
I wrote cURL like below. I was wondering how to fix this issue.

```
$ch = curl_init("https://app.kajabi.com/login");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Host: app.kajabi.com',
    'Connection: keep-alive',
    'Cache-Control: max-age=0',
    'sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="99"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1',
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.84 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site: none',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-User: ?1',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest: document',
    'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
    'Cookie: _kjb_session=795006a5538f30410ce2f56bd813ddb0; __cf_bm=7iLyh_LWPmJjzo07YdEJQaE_RT0LPS2R6NL1Hp3Li6g-1649142817-0-Ae4i2Gq5QTr+PktvLBJEV8MHcgGTw5ADVHkedUa3JTcVLHEDTyE01Nw6qsZtmjs7Quu+phKNOlCtu/8Cxpdwxec=; __cfruid=531ca052551b47923660c7b1832af0f2ea867981-1649142817; _kjb_ua_components=41e11a8e3c73294e1d2e0f1813e1f86d'
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    print "Error: " . curl_error($ch);
    exit();
}
echo $response;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried putting the response into a file, and it appears that the response is in gzip format.
`file_put_contents('temp.gz',$response)`

I extracted the archive and found that it's a HTML document telling you that *the access is denied*.

You can show the response directly in the output of your php script, though:

```
$decoded_response = gzdecode($response);
echo $decoded_response;
```

And maybe you should check whether the content is actually gzip before attempting to use `gzdecode`; see this thread: [php curl, detect response is gzip or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281630/php-curl-detect-response-is-gzip-or-not)

---

**Edit:**
You can let php automatically do the decoding by setting `CURLOPT_ENCODING` to `''`:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init("https://app.kajabi.com/login");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Host: app.kajabi.com',
    'Connection: keep-alive',
    'Cache-Control: max-age=0',
    'sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="99"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1',
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.84 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site: none',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-User: ?1',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest: document',
    'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
    'Cookie: _kjb_session=795006a5538f30410ce2f56bd813ddb0; __cf_bm=7iLyh_LWPmJjzo07YdEJQaE_RT0LPS2R6NL1Hp3Li6g-1649142817-0-Ae4i2Gq5QTr+PktvLBJEV8MHcgGTw5ADVHkedUa3JTcVLHEDTyE01Nw6qsZtmjs7Quu+phKNOlCtu/8Cxpdwxec=; __cfruid=531ca052551b47923660c7b1832af0f2ea867981-1649142817; _kjb_ua_components=41e11a8e3c73294e1d2e0f1813e1f86d'
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    print "Error: " . curl_error($ch);
    exit();
}
echo $response;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting un-handled GZIP from Curl because you are manually setting the `Accept-Encoding:` header in your header array, rather than letting Curl handle it. Curl then gets an unexpectedly-encoded response and goes "I dunno, you deal with this".

You're telling the remote side "I want things handled *this* way" but you're not actually telling the *local* side.

**Easy fix:** Remove the `Accept-Encoding:` header from your header array, optionally move those encoding specifications to the `CURLOPT_ENCODING` setting you added in your own answer, but I would say that this is unnecessary as curl will prefer compression anyway.

Other headers that you should likely not be manually setting:

- `Host:` unnecessary unless you need a value other than the hostname in the URL
- `Connection:` client needs to be aware
- `Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:` client needs to be aware, browser-specific